# how to snip or crop or white-fill a large. expanded (by 10%) rectangle outside of a polygon with ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, gis, map-projections

this question is a follow-up of my [prior SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354768/how-to-snip-or-crop-or-white-fill-the-area-outside-of-a-polygon-with-ggplot2) and is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286643/ggplot2-gis-plotting-inside-polygon-area).

i'm just trying to white-fill an area 10% bigger than a simple polygon with ggplot2.  maybe i'm grouping things wrong?  here's a photo of the spike with reproducible code below

[image]

```
# reproducible example
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(raster)

shpct.tf <- tempfile() ; td <- tempdir()

download.file( 
    "ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/pvs/tiger2010st/09_Connecticut/09/tl_2010_09_state10.zip" ,
    shpct.tf ,
    mode = 'wb'
)

shpct.uz <- unzip( shpct.tf , exdir = td )

# read in connecticut
ct.shp <- readShapePoly( shpct.uz[ grep( 'shp$' , shpct.uz ) ] )

# box outside of connecticut
ct.shp.env <- gEnvelope( ct.shp )
ct.shp.out <- as( 1.2 * extent( ct.shp ), "SpatialPolygons" )


# difference between connecticut and its box
ct.shp.env.diff <- gDifference( ct.shp.env , ct.shp )
ct.shp.out.diff <- gDifference( ct.shp.out , ct.shp )


library(ggplot2)


# prepare both shapes for ggplot2
f.ct.shp <- fortify( ct.shp )
env <- fortify( ct.shp.env.diff )
outside <- fortify( ct.shp.out.diff )


# create all layers + projections
plot <- ggplot(data = f.ct.shp, aes(x = long, y = lat))  #start with the base-plot 

layer1 <- geom_polygon(data=f.ct.shp, aes(x=long,y=lat), fill='black')

layer2 <- geom_polygon(data=env, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group), fill='white')

layer3 <- geom_polygon(data=outside, aes(x=long,y=lat,group=id), fill='white')

co <- coord_map( project = "albers" , lat0 = 40.9836 , lat1 = 42.05014 )

# this works
plot + layer1 

# this works
plot + layer2

# this works
plot + layer1 + layer2

# this works
plot + layer2 + co

# this works
plot + layer1 + layer3

# here's the problem: this breaks
plot + layer3 + co

# this also breaks, but it's ultimately how i want to display things
plot + layer1 + layer3 + co

# this looks okay in this example but
# does not work for what i'm trying to do-
# cover up points outside of the state
plot + layer3 + layer1 + co
```

Comment: From the documentation of the `coord_map` function: "This is still experimental, and if you have any advice to offer regarding a better (or more correct) way to do this, please let me know". My bet is that you found a bug in this "experimental" function

Comment: Do you mean 10% larger than the dimensions of the bounding box of the poly?

Comment: @jbaums yes, i do.  so for this example, 10% beyond the furthest extent of connecticut's state borders in every direction :)

Comment: Do you have your heart set on a `ggplot2` solution? Assuming I understand your intentions, this stuff is fairly straightforward with base plotting.

Comment: To simplify your example code, you could replace all of the lines involved in buffering out and differencing your shapes with lines 5-7 from [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26308426/980833). I have to agree with jbaums too: I ran your code yesterday and upvoted the question, but once I realized it was a problem with ggplot and `coord_map` in particular, I stopped digging, since ggplot is so frigging difficult (for me at least) to debug! With a **base** or **lattice** plotting function, I'd have at least given it a shot.

Comment: @jbaums i do hope to solve this with `ggplot2` because other components of [the full code i'm trying to perfect](https://github.com/davidbrae/swmap) rely on geom_tile().  that said, i would certainly appreciate a non-ggplot2 solution if you think it's straightforward

Comment: @JoshO'Brien very sneaky!  i have edited my example, and i'll use that in the future.  thank you!

Comment: @JoshO'Brien & Anthony: careful - `1.1 * extent(x)` is not the same as adding 10% to each side, unless both axes span the equator. In the present case, `1.1 * xmax` and `1.1 * ymax` actually subtract 10% from those bounds (since `xmax` and `ymax` are negative).

Comment: @jbaums -- Not quite right. **raster** defines a method for `*` when applied to an `Extent` class object, and it's smarter than that. Try `extent(10,20,10,20) * 1.2` to see that it does in fact **add** to each dimension. (Do notice that you have to multiply by `1.2` to get a 10% extension in each direction.) If you want to have a look at the code underlying `Extent`'s `*` method, you can get it by typing `getMethod("Arith", c("Extent", "numeric"))`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien ahh thank you for the explanation - I wasn't aware of that behaviour! Very sneaky indeed :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `coord_map', or more generally non-linear coordinates, internally interpolates vertices so that line is draw as a curve corresponding the coordinate.
In your case, interpolation will be performed between a point of the outer rectangle and a point of inner edge, which you see as the break.

You can change this by:

```
co2 <- co
class(co2) <- c("hoge", class(co2))
is.linear.hoge <- function(coord) TRUE
plot + layer1 + layer3 + co2
```

[image]

You can also find the difference of behavior here:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 90), y = 45), aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + co + ylim(0, 90)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 90), y = 45), aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + co2 + ylim(0, 90)
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Nice. Would you mind explaining what the two lines with `hoge` are doing? I don't see `is.linear.hoge` used again later (or is it called by `coord_map`?).

Comment: wow.  like @jbaums, i am curious for more detail about what is going on here and why these additional lines are necessary.. but this clearly solves the problem presented.  thank you!!

Comment: played with this a bit, it looks like including `coord_fixed()` in your final call is necessary if your layers include anything that is not `geom_polygon`

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd go about it with base plotting functions. It wasn't entirely clear to me whether you need the "background" polygon to be differences against the state polygon, or whether it's fine for it to be a simple rectangle that will have the state poly overlain. Either is possible, but I'll do the latter here for brevity/simplicity.

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster) # for extent() and crs() convenience

# download, unzip, and read in shapefile
download.file(file.path('ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/pvs/tiger2010st/09_Connecticut/09',
                        'tl_2010_09_state10.zip'), f <- tempfile(), mode='wb')
unzip(f, exdir=tempdir())
ct <- readOGR(tempdir(), 'tl_2010_09_state10')

# define albers and project ct
# I've set the standard parallels inwards from the latitudinal limits by one sixth of
# the latitudinal range, and the central meridian to the mid-longitude. Lat of origin 
# is arbitrary since we transform it back to longlat anyway.
alb <- CRS('+proj=aea +lat_1=41.13422 +lat_2=41.86731 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-72.75751
           +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs')
ct.albers <- spTransform(ct, alb)

# expand bbox by 10% and make a polygon of this extent
buf <- as(1.2 * extent(ct.albers), 'SpatialPolygons')
proj4string(buf) <- alb

# plot without axes
par(mar=c(6, 5, 1, 1)) # space for axis labels
plot(buf, col='white', border=NA)
do.call(rect, as.list(c(par('usr')[c(1, 3, 2, 4)], col='gray90'))) 
# the above line is just in case you needed the grey bg
plot(buf, add=TRUE, col='white', border=NA) # add the buffer
plot(ct.albers, add=TRUE, col='gray90', border=NA)
title(xlab='Longitude')
title(ylab='Latitude', line=4)
```

Now, if I understand correctly, despite being in a projected coordinate system, you want to plot axes that are in the units of another (the original) coordinate system. Here's a function that can do that for you.

[EDIT: I've made some changes to the following code. It now (optionally) plots the grid lines, which are particularly important when plotting axis in units that are in a different projection to the plot.]

```
axis.crs <- function(plotCRS, axisCRS, grid=TRUE, lty=1, col='gray', ...) {
  require(sp)
  require(raster)
  e <- as(extent(par('usr')), 'SpatialPolygons')
  proj4string(e) <- plotCRS
  e.ax <- spTransform(e, axisCRS)
  if(isTRUE(grid)) lines(spTransform(gridlines(e.ax), plotCRS), lty=lty, col=col)
  axis(1, coordinates(spTransform(gridat(e.ax), plotCRS))[gridat(e.ax)$pos==1, 1],
       parse(text=gridat(e.ax)$labels[gridat(e.ax)$pos==1]), ...)
  axis(2, coordinates(spTransform(gridat(e.ax), plotCRS))[gridat(e.ax)$pos==2, 2],
       parse(text=gridat(e.ax)$labels[gridat(e.ax)$pos==2]), las=1, ...)
  box(lend=2) # to deal with cases where axes have been plotted over the original box
}

axis.crs(alb, crs(ct), cex.axis=0.8, lty=3)
```

[image: map]